# Extract unique values within text list, where each item has constant common prefix or suffix or both

Tags: r, regex

I have a set of variables with different prefixes and suffixes. There are two types. One type has only prefix. The second type has prefix, then a number, then suffix. The numbers in each type are unordered. Here is some example code of the two types

```
VarNamesType1 <- c("Prefix12",  "Prefix11",  "Prefix144", "Prefix122")
VarNamesType1> 
[1] "Prefix12"  "Prefix11"  "Prefix144" "Prefix122"
```

Here are the variable names with a prefix and suffix

```
VarNamesType2 <- c("Pre29Suffix","Pre23Suffix2"  "Pre25Suffix2","Pre27Suffix2" )
VarNamesType2>

[1] "Pre29Suffix"  "Pre23Suffix2"  "Pre25Suffix2"  "Pre27Suffix2"
```

Is there a way to find the unique values within those list of variable types. So for VarNamesType1 use a code find the values 2,1,44,22 and for VarNamesType2 find 9,3,5,7. Is it be possible to find the unique numbers for both types with the same code? Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

EDIT1- thank you to poster who showed soulution remove all text. however the prefix and suffix can contain numbers too. Therefore, removing text will not work. I've updated the example code.

EDIT2- I've now been able to use this to find the prefix part. I'm not sure how to find the suffix part.

```
find_common_start <- function(strings) {
  max_length = min(nchar(strings))
  for(len in max_length:1) {
    if(length(unique(substr(strings, start = 1, stop = len))) == 1) {
      return(substr(strings[[1]], start = 1, stop = len))
    }
  }
}

> find_common_start(VarNamesType1)
[1] "Prefix1"
 find_common_start(VarNamesType2)
[1] "Pre2"
```

Can this be adapted to do the suffix?

EDIT3 - Solved it by writing this in end

```
find_unique <- function(FindUnique) {
  max_presuffix = min( nchar( FindUnique ) )
  for ( i in 1:max_presuffix ) {
    if( length( unique( substr( FindUnique , start = 1, stop = i) ) ) == 1 ) {
      prefix <-(substr( FindUnique[[1]], start = 1, stop = i )) }
    if( length( unique( substr( FindUnique, start = nchar(FindUnique) - i   , stop = nchar( FindUnique ) ) ) )  == 1  ) {
      suffix <-(substr( FindUnique[[1]], start = nchar( FindUnique )- i , stop = nchar( FindUnique )[1] ) ) }
  }
  if (exists("prefix")){ FindUnique <- sub( prefix ,"", FindUnique ) } 
  if (exists("suffix")){FindUnique <- sub( suffix ,"", FindUnique ) }
return( FindUnique )  
}
    
> find_unique(VarNamesType1) 
[1] "2"  "1"  "44" "22"
> find_unique(VarNamesType2) 
[1] "9"  "3"  "5"  "7"
```

Comment: Remove all the letters, that should leave you the numbers. So the question, is it always numbers that are prefixed and suffixed?

Comment: it is common prefix and suffix, which can contain numbers. thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can use `readr::parse_number`, or remove all letters or extract all numbers with regexes.

**With `parse_number`**

```
readr::parse_number(VarNamesType1)

[1]  2  1 44 22

readr::parse_number(VarNamesType2)

[1] 9 3 5 7
```

**with regex**

```
stringr::str_extract(VarNamesType2, '\\d+') |>
    as.integer()

[1] 9 3 5 7
```

All values in the example data are already unique, but if we are interested in unique values for any dataset, we can pipe the output into `unique()`, as in:

```
readr::parse_number(VarNamesType1) |> unique()
```

**EDIT**

the OP informed the Suffixes and Prefixes may have numbers.
In that case, parse_number() would not work, and we would have to use a regex-based approach.

We must have consistent "prefix" or "suffix" patterns in order to do that. We can use `stringr::str_remove_all` , to remove either the prefix or the suffix, and collapse them with "|":

```
library(glue)
library(stringr)

prefix<-'Pre2'
suffix<-'Suffix2'

str_remove_all(VarNamesType2, glue('^{prefix}|{suffix}$')) |>
    as.integer()

[1] 9 3 5 7
```

Comment: I think we should first wait with OP to confirm the input is correct. If it is indeed just numbers wrapped with letters, then this post is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for this, but this won't work if the prefix or suffix contains a number.

Comment: Yes, it deoesnt. Please provide a pattern for the prefixes or suffixes, we can not help you without that. Please provide a proper reproducible example, with several different prefixes and suffixes.

Comment: I've just updated my example code, thanks

Comment: Ok, please see the updated answer

Comment: I was looking for the code to recognise that Pre2 and Suffix2 are consistent and for it to be removed, not for it to be specified.

Comment: Ok, but we have to define rules on how to recognize the suffix/prefixes. As an example, how would the regex identify in the string "Pre22Suffix2", if is composed by prefix = 'Pre2', ID=2, suffix = 'Suffix1' or prefix = 'Pre', ID=22, suffix = "Suffix2"?

Comment: If we want to programatically recognize the prefix, we need the common pattern for these.

Comment: I've found a code to do the prefix part (edited my post again), I now need to find a way to either manipulate this to do the suffix part, or to reverse the text (treat suffix as the prefix) then note number of characters and remove the number of characters at the end.

Comment: I did not delete this answer so these comments linger on before we reach a correct answer. Please see my new answer, i think i got it now.

Answer (score 0):

I finally understood the question.
To check for unique values burried between constants (prefix and suffix),
we can first split the string into single characters, then drop list elements with lengths ==1 with `purrr::pmap`

```
library(purrr)


pmap(strsplit(VarNamesType2, ''), ~unique(c(...)))%>%
    keep(~length(.x) > 1) %>%
    unlist()%>%
    as.integer()

[1] 9 3 5 7
```

Comment: i cut and pasted as it is, and getting this error
Error: Element 1 of `.l` must have length 1 or 13, not 12

Comment: I cant reproduce this problem. Are you using the same data? `VarNamesType2 <- paste0( "Pre2" ,  c(9,3,5,7) , "Suffix2")`

Comment: Maybe your data has NAs?

Comment: yes i'm using VarNamesType2 <- paste0( "Pre2" ,  c(9,3,5,7) , "Suffix2"). Is there another package that needs to be used?

Comment: Just purrr. It runs smoothly in a fresh r session with just the `purrr` package loaded.

Comment: R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
other attached packages:
[1] purrr_0.3.4

Comment: restarted and on 4.1.2 and it still doesn't work. Thanks for trying though

Comment: Sorry I cant tell whats wrong. Please update the question if you find out.

Comment: I couldn't use it. I ended up writing a function to do it in end. Thanks anyways for your help

Answer (score 0):

I eventually wrote this, which answers my own question.

```
find_unique <- function(FindUnique) {
  max_presuffix = min( nchar( FindUnique ) )
  for ( i in 1:max_presuffix ) {
    if( length( unique( substr( FindUnique , start = 1, stop = i) ) ) == 1 ) {
      prefix <-(substr( FindUnique[[1]], start = 1, stop = i )) }
    if( length( unique( substr( FindUnique, start = nchar(FindUnique) - i   , stop = nchar( FindUnique ) ) ) )  == 1  ) {
      suffix <-(substr( FindUnique[[1]], start = nchar( FindUnique )- i , stop = nchar( FindUnique )[1] ) ) }
  }
  if (exists("prefix")){ FindUnique <- sub( prefix ,"", FindUnique ) } 
  if (exists("suffix")){FindUnique <- sub( suffix ,"", FindUnique ) }
return( FindUnique )  
}
    
> find_unique(VarNamesType1) 
[1] "2"  "1"  "44" "22"
> find_unique(VarNamesType2) 
[1] "9"  "3"  "5"  "7"
```

Comment: Why is this returning `c(9, 3, 5, 7, 88)` if the provided `VarNamesType2` does not the last element with an 88? the data you provided is `VarNamesType2 <- paste0( "Pre2" ,  c(9,3,5,7) , "Suffix2")`, which has 4 elements, whereas the output from this answer suggests there are 5 elements

Comment: sorry I was working with VarNamesType2 <- paste0( "Pre2" ,  c(9,3,5,7,88) , "Suffix2")  to test if it works with different string lengths as they were all single length numbers. Apologies will edit again.

Comment: Now i can reproduce your error with my answer. Will work on that

Answer (score 0):

A working (although a but convoluted) tidyverse answer.

This relies on splitting the strings into lists of single characters, then finding the number of consecutive character positions which have only a single unique value both in the natural order (prefix) and `rev()`erse order (suffix)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)

splitted_strings<-list(
    strsplit(VarNamesType2, ''),
    rev_char_list = map(strsplit(VarNamesType2, ''), rev)
)

indexes<-splitted_strings %>%
    map_int(., \(x) sum(
        x %>%
        tibble(temp = .) %>%
        unnest_wider(temp)%>%
        map_int(~length(unique(.x))) %>%
        data.table::rleid(.)==1
        )) %>%
    set_names(c('prefix', 'suffix'))

str_sub(VarNamesType2,
        start = indexes['prefix']+1,
        end = -(indexes['suffix']+1))

[1] "9"  "3"  "5"  "7"  "88"
```

Comment: + )
Error in unnest_wider(., temp) : could not find function "unnest_wider"

Comment: it needed library(tidyr) to make it work. Thanks

Comment: I simplified the code a bit, and the Initial answer was missing library(tidyr), as you already pointed out.

Comment: it doesn't work for both VarNamesType2 and VarNamesType1, if is substitute in first one this happens
> str_sub(VarNamesType2, nchar_prefix+1, -(nchar_suffix+1))
[1] "" "" "" ""

Answer (score 0):

You could use {unglue}:

```r
VarNamesType1 <- paste0("Prefix1" ,  c(2,1,44,22))
VarNamesType2 <- paste0( "Pre2" ,  c(9,3,5,7) , "Suffix2")

# parse all your strings and extract the info in a table
pattern <- "{prefix=Prefix1|Pre2}{n=\\d+}{suffix}"
df <- unglue::unglue_data(
  c(VarNamesType1, VarNamesType2), pattern, convert = TRUE)
df
#>    prefix  n  suffix
#> 1 Prefix1  2        
#> 2 Prefix1  1        
#> 3 Prefix1 44        
#> 4 Prefix1 22        
#> 5    Pre2  9 Suffix2
#> 6    Pre2  3 Suffix2
#> 7    Pre2  5 Suffix2
#> 8    Pre2  7 Suffix2

df$n
#> [1]  2  1 44 22  9  3  5  7
```

You can also give several patterns that will be tried in turn, here we have `NA`s because the suffix is inexistant in type 1 rather than `""`

```
patterns <- c("{prefix=Prefix1}{n}", "{prefix=Pre2}{n}{suffix=Suffix2}")
unglue::unglue_data(
  c(VarNamesType1, VarNamesType2), patterns, convert = TRUE)
#>    prefix  n  suffix
#> 1 Prefix1  2    <NA>
#> 2 Prefix1  1    <NA>
#> 3 Prefix1 44    <NA>
#> 4 Prefix1 22    <NA>
#> 5    Pre2  9 Suffix2
#> 6    Pre2  3 Suffix2
#> 7    Pre2  5 Suffix2
#> 8    Pre2  7 Suffix2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: i think i've confused everyone by using the code VarNamesType1 <- paste0("Prefix1" ,  c(2,1,44,22))
VarNamesType2 <- paste0( "Pre2" ,  c(9,3,5,7) , "Suffix2"). as it gave everyone a clue as to what the prefix and suffix is. I've edited the question now. I wanted to find a code to find and remove the prefix and suffix, without it being specified. Thanks for looking at it. I was hoping a function could have done it, but in the end I answered it myself in the end with a loop in one of the answers. Thanks

Comment: The pb is you cannot know reliably if the prefix is Pre2 or Pre23 by looking at for example Pre234something. If there is something that defines robustly a prefix we can find a solution

Comment: I know it won't be full proof. I knew it would be difficult to get across what I wanted. I first started with a prefix and suffix that was text. So I recieved solution removing text.  The variables I use tend to be questionnaire types, eg. Qnumber_rowN_columnN. These are typical of the patterns I find: Type1<-c("Q15_1_1","Q15_1_2", "Q15_1_3") 
Type2<-c("Q15_7_1","Q15_8_1","Q15_9_1")
Type3<-c("Q15_A_1","Q15_B_1","Q15_C_1")
Type4<-c("Q15_B_1_3","Q15_B_2_3","Q15_B_3_3") . My solution works for me but I agree with you in a wider context the code is not intelligent to semantically know. thanks

Comment: well if your actual prefixes contain number but never finish with them (e.g. they finish with underscores) we can find a good solution. But if your solution works, that's great.

Comment: I think the prefixes and suffixes can be found programatically, as they are constant across all elements. My answer addressed that, but somehow failed when there are no suffixes